# UIImageView not releasing memory (according to VM Tracker) - Low Memory Warnings & Terminate

Tags: ios, uiimageview, out-of-memory, xcode-instruments

I'm really struggling with running out of memory in my app. The are the basic operations that I'm performing, as specified below. Note that whenever a user takes a picture with the camera, I save two different versions of it--one is a preview (for fast loading), and one with high quality for zooming and marking up later.

Here is a list of my order of operations:

1. At app launch, show thumbnails of images that have been taken in the app (obviously, at first launch of the app, this list is empty).
2. Touch camera button to launch the `UIImagePickerController`
3. User takes a photo and saves it (again, a preview is saved and a full scale photo is saved)
4. The list of thumbnails refreshes and shows the new preview image. Again, the overall size of "Image IO" in the VM Tracker instrument is still very small (increased by maybe 0.5MB tops).
5. User touches one of the preview images, which launches a different view controller that does the following:

   - Create new UIImageView, load the image, add as a subview to View Controllers view
   - Suddenly, "Image IO" jumps by 30MB.

The wouldn't be a big deal, but when I go back (navigation controller pop), neither the "Image IO" type nor the "Dirty" type decreases in size. It's as if the UIImageView is not being destroyed. Every time I push this view controller and load an image, the size increases by 30MB, and popping never decreases it.

I'm using ARC, so I'm not calling release myself, but I would expect that it would be destroyed when I pop the view controller.

Just FYI, the settings I'm using for saving the preview and the full image are:

Preview: `[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 400)], 0.4f) writeToFile:previewPath atomically:NO];`

Full: `[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image , 0.8f) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];`

My main concern is (1) figuring out how to get rid of the memory used from the UIImage after I pop the containing view controller, but I'd also like to know (2) why the image is 30MB when loaded.

Comment: (1) I have already seen similar problem with image view, try setting its image to "nil" before popping the controller and see if the problem persists.
(2) Depends of the size of the image but uncompressed image might take a lot of space (4000x2000) would take 32MB. If this is the issue you should take a look a bit about "tiling" (I think it was even described in WWDC)

Comment: @MaticOblak, good recommendations. For (1), I tried setting the view which contained the image view to nil, and that didn't work, but you have a good point. I could try creating an instance variable for both the UIImageView and the UIImage and set both to nil (UIImage first, of course) before popping and see if that works. For (2) thanks for the info--I'll definitely look that up. :)

Comment: @MaticOblak, #1 worked! I explicitly set the UIImage AND the UIImageView to nil (not sure if both are needed), and sure enough, it released the memory. **If you'll post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted solution!** Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Matic Oblak...

(1) I have already seen similar problem with image view, try setting its image to "nil" before popping the controller and see if the problem persists.

RESULT: I explicitly set the UIImage AND the UIImageView to nil (not sure if both are needed), and sure enough, it released the memory.

Answer (score 5):

i'm worked on image editor app and this help me lot for reduce memory use.Try this

don't load images with [UIImage imageNamed:] for load image in ImageView,it's cause memory issue when no.of images are more,

use this,

```
 NSString * imgpath= [ [ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];

 ImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imgpath];
```